# write and read from ttyUSB0, can't get response

Tags: linux, terminal, raspbian, tty

I'm not very experienced with the Linux tty's.
My environment is a Raspbian with a prolific USB-serial.

What works:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 38400
cu -l /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 38400
```

`cu` to `/dev/ttyUSB0` works. I can write my commands to the terminal and get response from the other terminal within 300ms.

What not works:
in one terminal

```
echo "command" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

in another terminal (running before echo)

```
cat < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

or

```
tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0
```

there is no output.

But when i `echo "command" > /dev/ttyUSB0` and have `cu` open, I can see the echoed command and the response from the other terminal there.

What am I missing?

best regards

Sundypha

ps: What I tried too, was a little python script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 38400, xonxoff=True)
ser.open()
if ser.isOpen():
    ser.write('command')
    response = ser.readline()
    print response
    ser.close()
```

did not work either, hangs on ser.readline()

Answer (score 0):

If you are not cat'ing the USB0 device as you echo to it, then yes, you will not see its output because it has been and gone.

try something like:

```
tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and then echo stuff into it.

Comment: I forgot to add this, I already did this and didn't work either.

I was cat'ing before echo it, and it hangs there with no output.