# using cat and echo to write to /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: bash, usb, tty

im using cat and echo to read and write to and from a usb serial device.

```
# shell session 1
echo "send to device" >/dev/ttyUSB0

# shell session 2
cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

this works great if i do this manually.
when running a script, the echo command somehow looses usually the first 1-4 characters of the string and the device only received the rest

example: device typically would receive "nd to device"

can someone give me a hint why this is?

Comment: Reading from a terminal doesn't return what was written to it. It's not a file.

Comment: no man, what the device is answering to the received command (RX) in this regard all good.

Comment: When you write, it goes to the device that's connect to the USB port. Unless that device is reflecting it back, you shouldn't expect to read the same thing.

Comment: i do have echo enabled on the device, so i can debug, what the device does is first repeat the incoming command then act on it

Comment: I can't see any reason why this would work differently in the script. Maybe it's a timing issue, and the device can't process multiple messages in rapid succession.

Comment: ya i think its def. some timing issue, but i cant see where or how. i was even doing things like "echo bla bla; sleep 2; echo bla bla" as i was assuming the host was writing too fast

Comment: Can you set up a tail of your device before you echo to it?

Comment: Yap, why? Is this strange?

Comment: I just saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28287785/356887) and I wondered maybe if the device only has a limited buffer for echoing, especially if it's a debug feature. I would think your manual invocation would only work though if you tailed first maybe. Idk.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Sorry, that's all I've got.

Comment: Hehe man, i had big hopes ;-) thanks anyways

Comment: What if i were to do "attach", like echo "hi" >>/dev/ttyUSB??? (Double >>)

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking this is absolutely no solution, but until there is a better one, i delay and slowly send char-by-char. this way it works.

Faster than 0.1sec per char becomes unstable.

Im using Windows 10 WSL1

```
command=""
command+="command one to deliver$"
command+="command two to deliver$"
command+="command three to deliver$"
command+="command four to deliver$"

local loopindex=$command
for ((i = 0; i < ${#loopindex}; i++)); do
    if [[ ${loopindex:$i:1} = "$" ]]; then
        echo "debug: newline"
        echo "" >/dev/ttyUSB
    else
        echo "debug: char=${loopindex:$i:1}"
        echo -n "${loopindex:$i:1}" >/dev/ttyUSB
    fi
    sleep 0.1
done
```